# Estimating total number of players based a rank subset

Tags: probability

I recently played a lottery game where there was a unique "first prize". A rank is randomly attributed to each player. You win if you get the first rank, otherwise you lose. So, my friends and I received a rank. I received 199, one received 133, another 45, etc.
The total number of player is never disclosed. How can I estimate the number of players who joined the game, and thus, the probability of winning? Note that a player cannot buy more than a ticket.

I initially had the feeling that it's about fitting a binomial cumulative density function, but the variable is clearly not iid as rank duplicates are impossible.

Comment: See the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lulu for pointing me in the right direction. So, to sum up, the number of player can be estimated with three methods. Let $N$ be the number of player, $m$ the highest rank (furthest from 1) and $k$ the number of samples we got:

1. Frequentist approach: $N=m+\frac{m}{k}-1$
2. Bayesian median: $N=m+\frac{m\: ln(2)}{k-1}$
3. Bayesian mean: $N=(m-1)\frac{k-1}{k-2}$